# How to understand this code piece in ruby?

Tags: ruby

In Metaprogramming Ruby I saw this code

```
class String
  def to_alphanumeric
    gsub /[^\w\s]/, ''
  end
end
```

Here it adds a method to_alphanumeric, which substitutes punctuations with whitespace, to the standard class String. What confuses me is, since we do not specify which object gsub works on, how does Ruby know here we actually mean gsub works on the String obj itself instead of something else? Or put it in another way, does Ruby automatically rewrite it as self.gsub?

Comment: parent and parent and parent and so on to find a method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implicit receiver in Ruby is always `self` (and `self` is different in different contexts, of course).

Ruby doesn't "automatically rewrite it as `self.gsub`" *per se*, because calling a private method with an explicit `self` receiver will raise an exception (and `gsub` is a public method here anyway).

Comment: I got confused. gsub is by default private, so why do you say it's "public here anyway"?